# Using Device Orientation on page load

Tags: javascript, device-orientation

I am trying to grab the alpha, beta and gamma coordinates through the [deviceorientation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DeviceOrientationEvent) event.

My code:

```
window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', function(event) {
  alert(event.alpha + ' : ' + event.beta + ' : ' + event.gamma);
});
```

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/myL17nzt/

This works great to constantly grab the coordinates as the device moves, but I would like to just grab the coordinates on page load and not make it listen for movement. I tried changing window.addEventListener to window.onload, but that didn't do the trick.

Any ideas how I could accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be better to have the listener remove itself.

```
function deviceOrientation(event) {
  alert(event.alpha + ' : ' + event.beta + ' : ' + event.gamma);
  window.removeEventListener('deviceorientation', deviceOrientation);
}
window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', deviceOrientation);
```

This way you don't have it being called for events that you don't care about. Some libraries have a function called `once` that removes the event listener after the first event occurence.

Comment: Thanks! Very nice and efficient solution

Comment: Just what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can set a variable to control the initial run and the rest of them. Something like this:

```
   var initial = true;    
   window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', deviceOrientation(event) {
     if (initial) {
       alert(event.alpha + ' : ' + event.beta + ' : ' + event.gamma);
       initial = false;
     }
   });
```

Not the best solution probably, but fastest one that I can think of right now.